# Change App icon released on Windows store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, advanced-installer

I have released eBike Lab 1.6.5 App(our App) on Microsoft Store. but the icon displayed on the store and icon which App is displayed with both are different one. I need to change icon on store currently displaying. I have updated store icon in both App manifest  and Advanced Installer -> Visual Assets page. Still it is showing old icon.

Answer (score 0):

For the update in the App manifest, there are server points to note.

1.The Store Logo actually appears in Dev Center, Report App, Write a Review and My Library.

2.Square 150X150 logo is used in stars pins an all apps, Store Listing Page…..
Please refer to the picture below for details:
 [image]

By default, the Store will use the logo images from your package when displaying your product's listing to customers. However, you have the option to prevent the Store from using the logo images in your app's packages when displaying your listing to customers on Windows 10 (including Xbox), 
and instead have the Store use only images that you upload. You can get the information in this official document: [Display only uploaded logo Images in the Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-screenshots-and-images#display-only-uploaded-logo-images-in-the-store).

Comment: I have updated the icons from Store Listing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-app-store-listings#store-listing-languages
As per you suggestion I have checked option for providing seperate econ for windows 10..Thanks for All